# Show colon in console.log output

Tags: javascript, for-loop, console.log

I have a simple loop function for a count down:

```
function countdown(numright) {
 for (i = 0; i <= numright; ++i) {
  (function (i) {
     setTimeout(function () {
          console.log( i +1,(numright - i));
        $("#result").html(i +1,(numright - i)));
     }, i * 1000);
  })(i);
 }
}
countdown(5);
```

I need to but a : so it shows:

```
1:5
2:4 etc....
```

Also need to output the results to a html element the above shows first number but not second. It works in the console 1 5 2 4 etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do some string concatenation and use `append` instead of `html`.

```
function countdown(numright) {
 for (i = 0; i <= numright; ++i) {
  (function (i) {
     setTimeout(function () {
        var out = i +1 + ':' + (numright - i);
        console.log(out);
        $("#result").append(out + '<br/>');
     }, i * 1000);
  })(i);
 }
}
countdown(5);
```

You also had an error in your original code which I've fixed.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9jRGy/)

Comment: Thanks Andy, this worked as well. What did you fix in the code so I know?

Comment: You had one too many close brackets in the `$("#result").html` line.

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this:

```
function countdown(numright) {
   var val;
   for (i = 0; i <= numright; ++i) {
      (function (i) {
          setTimeout(function () {
             val =  (i +1) + ':' + (numright - i);
             console.log(val);
             $("#result").append(val);
          }, i * 1000);
      })(i);
   }
}
countdown(5);
```

Comment: This work well, had to add a +</br />. but it worked. Thanks for The help.